# Git merging of parent and multiple child branches

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch `Parent3` and create two child branches from `Parent3` are `CB1` and `CB2`. `CB2` is updated and merged in `Parent3` frequently, but not `CB1`.

We need to move `Parent3` changes into `CB1` now. It resulted conflict in 10-20 files. I have resolved all the conflicts and pushed `CB1`. So now `Parent3` is able to merge into `CB1`.

The next step is now I need to merge `CB1` into `Parent3` and a strange issue is happening. For example, when I created child branches then in file index.html there is some commented code. The commented code is removed in `CB2` and merged into `Parent3` but now when I am pulling `CB1` into `Parent3` then the commented code is again coming as an additional code.

Can anyone please suggest an approach to resolve this?

Comment: There is no enough information to see what's happening. Did you eventually resolved merge conflicts wrongly? Which is the history of index.html (git log -- index.html). What is the status of that file in the other two branches? Did you change index.html on both branches?

Comment: Maybe writing down the commands with some explanation would be useful. Or some more details about the strange things. In general it's correct what you did.